# PyMongo insert_many() raising OperationFailure instead of BulkWriteError

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to replicate a production bug on my local machine which occurs when I insert multiple documents, one of which exceeds the maximum BSON size limit (16MB).

Upon calling `insert_many(documents, ordered=False)`, I'm getting an `OperationFailure` exception instead of the expected `BulkWriteError`. Additionally, even though I'm passing the `ordered=False` argument, the other valid documents are not being inserted. These two behaviors are contradictory to MongoDB's [documentation on `insert_many`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) ([here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#error-handling) and [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#execution-of-operations)). Why is an `OperationFailure` exception being raised instead of `BulkWriteError`?

(Using Python 3.10, PyMongo version 4.6.2 and latest MongoDB version 7.x (Docker container))

I actually want `BulkWriteError` to be raised because this exception object conveniently holds the raw documents that caused errors (within its `details` attribute).

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError, OperationFailure

documents = [
    {'x': 'a'},                 # valid
    {'x': 'b' * 20_000_000},    # invalid, causes error (too large)
    {'x': 'c'}                  # valid
]

with MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/") as client:
    collection = client['my_db']['my_collection']
    try:
        result = collection.insert_many(documents, ordered=False)
    except BulkWriteError:
        print('Does not enter here')    # this exception is not raised
    except OperationFailure:
        print('Enters here')            # this exception is raised
```

Side note: what's super weird is that I managed to replicate the `BulkWriteError` locally, but after leaving the code in my IDE and returning after 2 months, suddenly it's raising `OperationFailure`. I did not update the versions of anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should provide the full error message

Comment: also you can see here how this logic works https://stackoverflow.com/a/76396057/9492730

Comment: The documentation you linked is for the mongo shell, not python.  I suspect the error is occurring during serialization in the driver, so the request never event reaches the server, which is were a BulkWriteError will usually originate.

Comment: @Joe, mongo shell is a driver too (a little bit special but still). Usually all drivers behave the same especially from error handling POV.

Comment: Initially I missed that the expected error is exceeding the document size. In this case, @Joe is correct and the message will not be sent to the server

Comment: @dododo & @Joe , I really appreciate your comments. I'm racking my brain because, like I wrote, I was catching a BulkWriteError, and then something suddenly changed. Maybe it's related to the data I'm using to test, however all documents (`dict` objects) are the same in that regard, no?

@Joe are you suggesting that PyMongo is raising the error before sending it to the server?

Also, how do you explain why the valid documents are not being written (since I'm using `ordered=False`)?

Comment: Mongosh is not a driver, it is an application that uses the node.js driver.  When submitting a bulk insert, pymongo will use the [insert database command](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/insert/#insert) which contains a list of documents.  If one of the documents is too large to be serialized into that list, the driver never completes forming the command, so it is never sent to the server, and the server cannot honor the "ordered" option that it never saw.

Comment: @Joe I looked at the Docker logs for the Mongo container and saw that it reported the large document error. So doesn't that mean the request is reaching the Mongo server? Can you please propose a solution to my parallel inserts problem?